# Python defining unique class instance/object when threading

Tags: python, multithreading, class, object, multiprocessing

I am dealing with threading and I have a function which creates & calls a class instance "a" and then calls the function inside of the class with "a" reference object.
The problem is, when I call the function multiple times before the thread/process ends, the variable in "a" instance get merged and I get mixed outputs..

So, is there a way to automatically create another instance "b" when "a" is occupied or being used for the same class ?
Also, is there any better method to deal with this ?..

Comment: If each call to a function creates an object, you need to go out of your way for the objects created by different function calls to be able to see each other or otherwise have any kind of shared state.  Not being able to see how you're creating these "a" objects and causing them to have shared state makes it very difficult to suggest how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're looking for queue threading
https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

`The queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be exchanged safely between multiple threads. The Queue class in this module implements all the required locking semantics.`

`The module implements three types of queue, which differ only in the order in which the entries are retrieved. In a FIFO queue, the first tasks added are the first retrieved. In a LIFO queue, the most recently added entry is the first retrieved (operating like a stack). With a priority queue, the entries are kept sorted (using the heapq module) and the lowest valued entry is retrieved first.`

How to implement threads into queues there are a lot of tutorials on YouTube.